# Change worker node role tag in Kubernetes v1.25.1

Tags: kubernetes

I tried to set role for Kubernetes worker node this way:

```
kubernetes@kubernetes1:~$ kubectl label node kubernetes2 node-role.kubernetes.io/worker=worker2
node/kubernetes1 labeled
kubernetes@kubernetes1:~$

kubernetes@kubernetes1:~$ kubectl get nodes
NAME          STATUS     ROLES                  AGE   VERSION
kubernetes1   Ready      control-plane,worker   12d   v1.25.1
kubernetes2   NotReady   worker                 12d   v1.25.1
kubernetes3   Ready      worker                 12d   v1.25.1
kubernetes4   Ready      worker                 12d   v1.25.1
```

But for all work nodes I get role `worker` Any idea how I can set custom label?

Answer (score 1):

**You're assigning a label to a node, not changing the actual role of the node**. You can assign the role (controlplane/worker/etcd) to a node when you're creating your cluster for the 1st time.

If you want to get list of labels assigned to all the nodes, run

```
kubectl get nodes --show-labels
```

Comment: Thanks, but how I can do it dynamically from the shell?

Comment: do what exactly?

Comment: how to change role value to get proper value when I run `kubectl get nodes`